# Purchasing my items as a test with in app billing? (error: RPC:AEC:0)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

When I purchase Googles designated 'products' in my android app it runs successfully when I try to purchase my own it asks I enter payment information then upon entering the fake credit card details google provides gives me the error:

> "ERROR Update could not be downloaded due to an error (error while
>   retrieving information from server RPC:AEC:0"

and sometimes:

> Error processing purchase. [DF-BPA-13]

The in app item is in the published state so I don't think that is what's causing it, the app itself is unpublished.

I just want to make sure my in app items will work as expected before I publish it!